# Difference between React defaultProps and inline props

Tags: reactjs

What (if any) is the functional difference between these? In both cases the spread props override the preset props. What reasons would there be to use one syntax over the other?

### 1. default props

```
const Input = (props) => (
  <input {...props} />
);

Input.defaultProps = {
  className: "input",
};
```

### 2. inline props

```
const Input = (props) => (
  <input className="input" {...props} />
);
```

Comment: In the specific (very simple) example you've shown, I don't see any reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: defaultProps should only be used for defensive programming. You shouldn't be using them for a shorthand way of adding props to a component. Your second example is much better because it is immediately recognizable and understandable by other devs that may be working on your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultProps` when, your component needs certain props to operate, but you are not sure if you would get it at all times. So you provide a default value for it. This will be set if your actual props is not present.

Your `spread` operator expands(or spreads) the given object. Each key, value pair is passed as prop to the component. You would use this in cases, where you are not sure of the props, your child component requires. So just spread it out and let the child use what it needs. (This is just once scenario)

In your question, you have mentioned that `spread` operator overrides the present props in both cases. The overriding behaviour is because of the position of spread operator and not because of use `defaultProps` or absence of the same.

So lets assume the below code. Here, `input` would receive `myClass` as prop in `className`. Because you are spreading the `props` after `className` in input.

```
const props = {
 className: 'myClass',
};

<input className="input" {...props} />
```

While in the below code, `input` would receive `input` as prop in `className`.

```
const props = {
 className: 'myClass',
};

<input {...props} className="input" />
```